# Angular-cli : index outdir path with multiple apps and indexes

Tags: angular-cli

I split my app into two apps : "app" / "app2" and I build them independently. They have their own module and their own `index.html`

My problem is that when I build "app2" the output path of index.html is not the root of the build folder.

Here is my `angular-cli.json` for app2 :

```
  "name": "app2",
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "dist-app2",
  "index": "./app/modules/app2/index.html", <-- location of my index
  "main": "./app/modules/app2/main-export.ts"
```

When I build I get a path of : `build-app2/app/modules/export/index.html` when I want it to be at the root : `build-app2/index.html`

I know how to do this with webpack but I would prefer not to eject and I'm pretty sure it can be done directly with the cli but can't figure out how.

I tried `./app/modules/export/index.html` and `app/modules/export/index.html` but the results are the same.

There was a discussion on github [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7309) but in the end no one provided a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've provided 2 answers here but the discussion is still going on [in this thread on the angular-cli repository](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7309) so have a look here too we will probably come up with a better solution at some point.

**New answer**
More maintainable and in line with the angular-cli way of handling a multi apps setup.

After reading some commits on the angular-cli repo I found out about the `appRoot` options in the `angular-cli.json` config file, it allows me to also generate components for each app using the cli in the proper folders and add them to the right module :

```
  "name": "app2",
  "root": "src/modules/app2",
  "appRoot": "."
  "outDir": "dist-app2",
  "assets": ["assets"],
  "index": "index.html"
```

this allows me to do things like `ng g c components/new-component --app app2` that will generate a new component in `src/modules/app2/components/new-component` and update `app2.module.ts` accordingly, I has to duplicate some files and folders but in the end it is way more maintainable and easier to understand. Hopefully the angular-cli docs will soon be updated with a reference to `appRoot`

edit : **old answer**

I managed to circumvent the problem, here is how :

- I changed my root folder for "app2" so that the index would be directly in the root
- I made all the other paths (polyfills, assets, ts.config etc...) needed relative to the root folder path

My `angular-cli.json` file now looks like this for "app2" :

```
  "name": "app2",
  "root": "src/app/modules/app2", <-- new root
  "outDir": "dist-app2",
  "assets": ["../../../assets/i18n"], <-- relative path to root
  "index": "index.html", <-- index.html is now directly in root
  "main": "main-export.ts", <-- so is my main file // optional though
  "polyfills": "../../../polyfills.ts", <-- relative path to root
  "tsconfig": "../../../tsconfig.app.json", <-- relative path to root
  "testTsconfig": "../../../tsconfig.spec.json", <-- relative path to root
  "styles": ["../../../scss/modules/export.scss"], <-- relative path to root
  "scripts": [],
  "environmentSource": "../../environments/environment.ts", <-- relative path to root
```

My output folder structure is now normal :

`dist-app2/index.html`